# Starting up a canister filter that has been off for a while

Tags: aquarium, fish, filters

We prepared an Eheim canister about a week ago and had also put some tank water in it but, because of a series of setbacks, we haven't been able to start the filter in our new tank. We are still not sure when we will be able to start it.

The filter is second hand but we washed the pads and media then put in some tank water.

Is it best to empty/clean the filter again, or can we just start it and let it run once we are ready?